# Myob Integration with salesforce

Tags: rest, api, salesforce, apex, myob

I am integrating Account Right Live with Apex using OAuth 2.0 . using the documentation of Myob.
We really Dont want to show Login screen.
Is there any method to Authenticate user  using OAuth 2.0 with Myob Account Username password Method ?
Do Myob Support OAuth 1.0 ? then Please Share link of Any Documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to get your user to log in at least once. Persist the refresh token and use that to obtain new access tokens when the old ones expire. Every now and then the refresh tokens will expire. Then your user will have to log in again. The whole point of this paradigm is to allow you to integrate without knowing your user's log in credentials.